# base64 image source not working on Cordova IOS

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, base64, cordova-ios

In My cordova based IOS application i need to show one image from a  base64 source but it is not rendering anything.

```
 <img id="cardImg"  src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>
```

the above simple `<img>` is working fine over browser but not in my cordova application.

this is my `<meta> tag` list

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:">
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=5,user-scalable=yes" name="viewport">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

> Cordova version : 6.5 and IOS Version: 10.2.1

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the image source directive to:

```
img-src 'self' data:;
```

Append in same meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; ***img-src 'self' data:;*** script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Answer (score 0):

There only one way to show image in iOS is using base64 format.You can use cordova-camera-plugin to to generate base64 image and put on img tag.I have set the flag to get data in jpeg,base64 in camera plugin.

**img id="cardImg"**

var imgdata=data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

**cardImg.src=imgdata;**

Comment: consider id of your img tag be "cardImg" to which we add imgdata which is a base64 string

Comment: hi ,

i have tried same but one diff instead of getting base64 from camera i took it from some other source.

Comment: There only one way to show image in iOS is using base64 format.